# Combining similar fields in Sql Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations

I currently have a query that reads as such:

```
SELECT c.Course_No
       , c.Description
       ,  e.Section_Id
       , COUNT(e.Section_ID) AS enrollment
FROM Enrollment e JOIN
     Section s
     ON e.Section_Id = s.Section_Id JOIN
     Course c
     ON s.Course_No = c.Course_No
Group by c.Course_No, c.Description, e.Section_Id
ORDER BY c.Course_No
```

It works fine, and here are a snippet of the results:

```
COURSE_NO              DESCRIPTION                                        SECTION_ID             ENROLLMENT             
---------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 
10                     Technology Concepts                                80                     1                      
20                     Intro to Information Systems                       81                     3                      
20                     Intro to Information Systems                       82                     2                      
20                     Intro to Information Systems                       83                     2                      
20                     Intro to Information Systems                       84                     2
```

My question for you guys is this:  Is there a way to combine the fields that have the same course description and different sectionID?  I would like to have all fields combined but I am not so sure how to do so.

Added prompt and expected result:  Generate an alphabetic listing containing the last names and final exam grade (FI) of students who scored above average on the final exam for section 90.

```
LAST_NAME                 NUMERIC_GRADE
------------------------- -------------
Da Silva                             92
Lopez                                91
```

Comment: Give us the expected result. Columns and sample data of output. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @anonyXmous added, thank you!

Comment: try @GordonLinoff's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.Course_No, c.Description, 
       LISTAGG(e.Section_Id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.Section_Id) as sections,
       COUNT(*) AS enrollment
FROM Enrollment e JOIN
     Section s
     ON e.Section_Id = s.Section_Id JOIN
     Course c
     ON s.Course_No = c.Course_No
Group by c.Course_No, c.Description
ORDER BY c.Course_No
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Gordon!